# Retrieve firebase analytics full detail of events

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

We have a project with analytics enabled which tracks custom events.

Recently we needed to report on a specific parameter on these events but found the parameter was not included in the parameter reporting options, we have enabled this but the previous events over the past couple of months do not include this parameter now.

Is there any way to get the full data of events tracked to retrieve the data of this specific parameter before it was included in the parameter reporting options?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, custom parameter reports are populated after you add them on your Firebase console.

[When you register custom parameters, a data card for each parameter is added to the related event-detail report. However, it may take up to 24 hours for the data card to appear](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en).